# Looking for a recommendation: Anatomical diagrams of animals commonly used in laboratory testing (potential surgical procedure emphasized)

Tags: book-recommendation, animal-models, surgery

I'm interested in either a book or a place to find well-drawn diagrams of animal anatomy. The emphasis if possible would be on anything which includes material related to the nervous system of neurosurgical procedure. I'm interested in diagrams or figures for animals commonly used in testing, that is mice, rats, or others. This would be similar to the diagrams shown in medical school. I'm interested in these from the perspective of someone doing surgical procedure on a testing specimen. Any recommendations (book or otherwise) would be greatly appreciated.

Also, if there is a better stack exchange site that you would recommend me asking this on, feel free to recommend and I can move my question there. I'm outside of either field (engineer), so apologies if I'm, not familiar with which subforum to ask this on, and let me know where to move the question.

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer if you are more specific about the procedure of interest.

Comment: Neurosurgery was given as area of interest. Procedure of interest would involve operations on the central nervous system (CNS) and peripheral nervous system, particularly that of the spinal cord. Interpretation of spectral frequencies/brain waves of specimen is also of interest. I'm in the early phase of planning so anything even tangential to this would still be valued.

Comment: Neurosurgery is very broad though; you could be looking for brain atlases or neurovasculature or peripheral nerves. And now you bring up spectral analyses? You really need to have more focus before asking a question here, it's like if you asked for a book on engineering and said you're interested in electrical and mechanical and industrial, while architecture and geology are also of interest as is anything tangential.